# how to load a query into arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to load some queries into vectors to avoid temporary tables in a function:

```
create table mytable
 ( eref  serial primarykey,
   edia  date,
   eimpte numeric);
 ---

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION peps(rseller integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare 
  dep_dia    date[]   := '{}';
  dep_impte  numeric[]:= '{}';
  dep_ref    integer[]:= '{}';
  ndepositos integer  :=0;
  rec        record;
begin 

for rec in 
    select eref, edia, eimpte from mytable order by edia, eimpte 
loop
      ndepositos:=ndepositos+1;
      dep_dia[ndepositos]  :=edia;
      dep_impte[ndepositos]:=eimpte;
      dep_ref[ndepositos]  :=eref;    
end loop; 
raise notice ' ndeps %', ndepositos;
end
$BODY$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

it does not work:

```
ERROR:  column "edia" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT edia
               ^
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't loop! Postgres provides a great [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) for this:

```
SELECT array_agg(eref), array_agg(edia), array_agg(eimpte)
FROM (SELECT * from mytable order by edia, eimpte) AS foo
INTO your variables
```

By putting the order by in a subquery, the aggregate functions will get the values in the order you want. This should be faster than looping.

Answer (score 0):

You are not having `edia` column while creating the table. Looking at reamining code, I feel your create table query should be like following:

```
create table mytable
 ( edia serial primarykey,
   eref  date,
   eimpte numeric);
```

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo, it does exist: create table mytable
 ( eref  serial primarykey,
   edia  date,
   eimpte numeric);
 ---